# SQL return multiple values from CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I rewrite this SQL statement to do what I need?

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE 
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME_1 IN (CASE 
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME_2 = 'X' THEN 'A' 
        WHEN COLUMN_NAME_2 = 'Y' THEN 'B', 'C' END)
```

Obviously I can't return multiple values from a CASE clause... so how else could I write this? I am pretty sure I am slow today because this seems so easy ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE
    (COLUMN_NAME_2 = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME_1 = 'A') OR
    (COLUMN_NAME_2 = 'Y' AND COLUMN_NAME_1 IN ('B', 'C'))
```

or

```
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE COLUMN_NAME_2 = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME_1 = 'A'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM Table WHERE COLUMN_NAME_2 = 'Y' AND COLUMN_NAME_1 IN ('B', 'C')
```

This presumes that you *only* want results with X or Y in COLUMN_NAME_2.  If you want other rows it's not possible to tell which ones from your original SQL.