# How to return multiple values from a SQL Case subquery without grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following SQL query where the CASE statement needs to return multiple values.

```
select TASK_NAME 
from TASK 
where TASK_TYPE in (          
    case 
        when (select USER_COUNTRY from USER) in (select COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRY where CONTINENT = 'Europe') then ('Adhoc', 'Resell')
        when (select USER_COUNTRY from USER) in (select COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRY where CONTINENT = 'Americas') then ('Classified', 'Bought', 'Handle')
        else ('None', 'Blank')
    end )
```

However, the number of WHEN clauses is not fixed as there may be more conditions. I don't think [SQL return multiple values from CASE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056121/sql-return-multiple-values-from-case-statement) will work.

I should also add that grouping is not recognised by the application which this query is passed to.

I apologise for not providing the tables. I will do so in due course. Just wanted to get this out there.

Comment: What do you mean by "needs to return multiple values?" Case statements by design function in the following manner - the first condition to be true will be returned. It sounds like you need a join, not a CASE.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the comparison to the `when` clauses and have the `case` return a scalar value indicating a match:

```
where 1 = (case when (select USER_COUNTRY from USER) in (select COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRY where CONTINENT = 'Europe') and Task_Type IN ('Adhoc', 'Resell')
                then 1
                when (select USER_COUNTRY from USER) in (select COUNTRY_NAME from COUNTRY where CONTINENT = 'Americas') and Task_Type IN ('Classified', 'Bought', 'Handle')
                then 1
                when Task_Type IN ('None', 'Blank')
                then 1
            end )
```

This is a rather strange set of conditions.  Are you sure you can't express the logic better using `JOIN`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the use of groups and joins are limited in the application. In fact. the query in my original post is a subquery.

Comment: @Confounder . . . My actual concern is that `USER` might have more than one row.  In that case, the SQL would typically generate an error.